# How to fix the 'mysql2' error when loading rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to start up the rails console ( not related to my previous questions since these are different errors ) and I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to fix this or what's even asking me to do. I'm running: ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux].

I type in the rails console command and get the following:

**ubuntu:~/environment/sample_app (sign-up) $ rails console**

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'mysql2' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError)
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:6:in `<main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1052:in `establish_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:51:in `establish_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:327:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:370:in `active_record_configured?'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:287:in `disconnect_database'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:111:in `preload'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
ubuntu:~/environment/sample_app (sign-up) $ rails console
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'mysql2' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError)
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:6:in `<main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1052:in `establish_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:51:in `establish_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:327:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:370:in `active_record_configured?'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:287:in `disconnect_database'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:111:in `preload'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

***UPDATE***
this is what my gemfile looks like currently.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'rails',                      '6.0.3.1'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
gem 'image_processing',           '1.9.3'
gem 'mini_magick',                '4.9.5'
gem 'active_storage_validations', '0.8.9'
gem 'bcrypt',                     '3.1.13'
gem 'faker',                      '2.11.0'
gem 'will_paginate',              '3.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate',    '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',             '3.4.1'
gem 'puma',                       '4.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails',                 '6.0.0'
gem 'webpacker',                  '4.2.2'
gem 'turbolinks',                 '5.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                   '2.10.0'
gem 'bootsnap',                   '1.4.6', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.2'
  gem 'byebug',  '11.1.3', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '4.0.2'
  gem 'listen',                '3.2.1'
  gem 'spring',                '2.1.0'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '3.32.2'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '3.142.7'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '4.3.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.4'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.3.8'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.16.2'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',         '1.2.3'
  gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '1.46.0', require: false
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# Uncomment the following line if you're running Rails
# on a native Windows system:
# gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I tried the suggestions given, but now my error looks like this when I try to run 'rails console'. Bundle install works fine.

```
ubuntu:~/environment/sample_app (sign-up) $ rails console
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'mysql2' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate mysql2 (>= 0.4.4), already activated mysql2-0.3.21. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (LoadError)
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:6:in `<main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1052:in `establish_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:51:in `establish_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `class_eval'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:327:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:370:in `active_record_configured?'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:287:in `disconnect_database'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:111:in `preload'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure ‘mysql2’ is included in your gem file and run `bundle install`

The key part of the error message is:

```
Error loading the 'mysql2' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
```

Comment: And if you run into problems installing that gem, it’s likely missing some OS level dependencies. On Ubuntu, use `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` to install the required libraries and then try bundle install again.

Comment: what line, exactly, am I supposed to add in my gemfile? I've tried to add it in, but it keeps giving me an error message.

Comment: Your Gemfile should contain the line `gem 'mysql2'`. With that line in place, does the command `bundle install` run cleanly or with errors? Post the contents of the Gemfile if you want someone to check it.

Comment: I updated so you could see my gemfile. Does that help?

Comment: Your gemfile is specifying a version for MySQL2 (0.3) while the error reports that rails expects >=0.4.4. Edit your gemfile to request 0.4.4 instead of 0.3.20, or remove the version specified so you’ll just get the newest version.

Comment: Of those options; you’re better off removing any version specifier for mysql2. So, Replace `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'` in your gemfile with `gem 'mysql2'`